# Is "true == !false" always true?

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic

This was raised in the office today. With the various types of computing, various languages and various boolean types. Is the following always true

```
true == !false;
```

Comment: ... perhaps not for very large versions of false.  (humor)

Comment: Maybe not in Javascript. [Javascript is completely bonkers](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/476826733576847360?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=tuxetuxe&utm_content=476831695078166528).

Answer (score 3):

While there should be no language where your expression can directly be false, there are quite a number of languages where the related expression

```
someTrueValue == !false
```

does not hold true. C and its variants, for instance. And Lisp variants, to name just a few. In these languages, there is one false value (zero or nil), everything else is considered true. So, `!false` will yield one of these true values, which can be different from `someTrueValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `true` and `false` are reserved keywords representing boolean values, it should always be true.

If the language happens to not reserve those keywords (ie: older versions of Python), you could always declare a variable with those names such that `true == !false` is false.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `true` and `false` being variables, `!` has different meanings in many languages. Though I don't know any language which uses `==` for something other than (some sort of) equality, it could be user-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is because !false equals true, and true always equals true.

Comment: There's one more step required in that reasoning. OP did not ask whether `true == !false` but  whether `true == !false` is true. So ... "Yes. It is because !false is true, and true equals true, and that is always true."

Answer (score 0):

If there was ever a language where (true == !false)==false then the language would be inconsistent with Boolean logic ('inconsistent' is being used here both informally and in a formal sense within Boolean logic) and the result of this would be that it would be possible to derive inconsistent logical assertions (such as true == false, or false == true).

The final result of this would be that there would be no trustworthy logical framework underpinning any of the use of conditionals within the language rendering it useless.